# Gorilla Mux routes not resolving

Tags: go, gorilla

So, I'm working on a simple RESTful API using Go and Gorilla Mux. I'm having issues with with my second route not working, it's returning a 404 error. I'm not sure what the problem is as I'm new to Go and Gorilla. I'm sure it's something really simple, but I can't seem to find it. I think it might be a problem with the fact that I'm using different custom packages.

This question is similar, [Routes returning 404 for mux gorilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831190/routes-returning-404-for-mux-gorilla), but the accepted solution didn't fix my problem

Here's what my code looks like:

Router.go:

```
package router

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
        Methods(route.Method).
        Path(route.Pattern).
        Name(route.Name).
        Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

    return router
}

var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "CandidateList",
        "GET",
        "/candidate",
        CandidateList,
    },
    Route{
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },
}
```

Handlers.go

```
package router

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Welcome!")
}

func CandidateList(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "CandidateList!")
}
```

Main.go

```
package main

import (
    "./router"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    rout := router.NewRouter()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", rout))
}
```

Going to just localhost:8080 returns Welcome! but going to localhost:8080/candidate returns a 404 Page Not Found error. I appreciate any input and help! Thanks!

This is an updated version of my Router.go file, there is still the same issue happening.

Router.go

```
package router

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
)

type Route struct {
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc).GetError()
    }

    return router
}

var routes = Routes{
   Route{
      "GET",
      "/candidate",
      CandidateList,
   },
   Route{
       "GET",
       "/",
       Index,
    },
}
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this and now it's working with the same code posted by OP. Try using [GetError()](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.GetError) to see if registering a route gives you any issue. Something like:


`err := router.Methods(route.Method).Path(route.Pattern).Name(route.Name).Handler(route.HandlerFunc).GetError()`

Comment: Adding .GetError() didn't return anything different then what I currently see.

Comment: Weird ... last thing I did that made it work was remove the `.Name()` function call when registering the routes.. try doing that and make sure you are not caching the responses.

Comment: Removed the .Name() call and the appropriate field in the Route and still no luck, I've added my updated Router.go file to the question.

Comment: Oh .. make sure to save the returned error:


`err := router.Methods()...GetError()` and check if it returns an error `if err != nil{ log.Println(err) }`

Comment: Are you certain you're working with the version of your router package shown here? Try putting all your code into one `main` file and testing the routes from there.

Comment: @AbelardoMendoza I added the code you suggested and this is all it output  2016/01/21 07:38:44 &{0xc8200124b0 0x5c840 [[GET] 0xc820018180] 0xc820010d20 true false Index <nil> <nil>} but I was able to get it to work. I don't know what I did to fix it, but I deleted the route, ran the app, then recreated the route with a different name and calling a different HandlerFunc and it works. There must have been a typo or artifact that it was holding onto.

Comment: @JimB I think you were onto the route cause of the problem, since my Router.go is in a different package than my Main.go it pulls in a copy of Router.go to the same directory instead of referencing the one in the subfolder. I'm thinking it wasn't pulling in the newest version of the Router.go because I was able to get it to run after removing the copied files and then running the app. Then adding in the route again.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my project was holding onto old versions of the Router.go and Handlers.go files in the main src directory. By removing these duplicate files and re-running Main.go with go run Main.go I was able to get the route to be recognized.

Comment: Do not use relative imports. Always import via the full path to avoid this, and other problems.